# How do you SELECT items based on COUNT(*) from another table? - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

My tables are like so:

**Tile**

```
Tile
---------------------------------
Id integer not null primary key
```

**TestSet**

```
TestSet
--------------------------------
Id integer not null primary key,
TileId integer not null,
CreatedAt datetime not null,
Outcome boolean
```

There is a 1:n relationship between Tile and TestSet.

I want to get the tiles that have a testSet with a true Outcome value on the most recent testSet (ordered by the CreatedAt column). My first attempt at it doesn't work as I want it to.

```
SELECT * FROM Tile
JOIN (SELECT TileId FROM (SELECT * FROM TestSet
WHERE tileId == 'Tile1'
ORDER BY __createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1)
WHERE Outcome=1) as ts ON ts.TileId == Tile.id;
```

The problem with the above statement is that the WHERE clause in the most inner SELECT statement is hardcoded.

Here's how I broke up the process:

> 1. Grab the most recent testSet.
> 2. SELECT only the tileId column from that testSet.
> 3. JOIN the tile table on the above statements to get a list of all the tiles.

I feel like I'm thinking about this the wrong way and I shouldn't really be doing a JOIN. But I don't have enough SQL experience to know exactly how to go about this problem. I'm using SQLite specifically in a mobile app, so are there any SQLite statements that can help me get the correct set of tiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Id FROM Tile
JOIN (SELECT TileId, Outcome, MAX(CreatedAt)
      FROM TestSet
      GROUP BY TileId, Outcome
      ) AS ts
ON ts.TileId == Tile.id
WHERE Outcome = 1;
```

Comment: Care to give an explanation of what you are doing? We don't generally like code only answers.

Comment: The inner SELECT only returns testSets with an outcome of true(1). SELECTing Outcome in the inner SELECT and moving the "WHERE Outcome = 1" to the outter SELECT worked well. Thank you for the tip. If you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @WiteCastle - I see I didn't completely understand the problem, but I see what you are saying. I've made the changes that you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate method. Since the tileid is already there in TestSet, this example uses only TestSet, but you can feel free to JOIN it with Tile table.

```
select * 
from testset t1
where createdat in 
(
  -- search the same table for the tileid and also ensure outcome is 1
  -- sort it by createAt latest to oldest date and choose only the first
  -- record
  select createdat 
  from testset t2
  where 
    t2.tileid = t1.tileid
    and outcome = 1
  order by t2.createdat desc
  limit 1
);
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/91548/3